# Pandas dataframe to extract data from csv file seperated by markers and save into excel sheets

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, data-extraction

I have a csv file which contains a time-based data, and I use a column "Marker" to help identify the idle time (value: 0) and a set of useful data collection steps(value: 1 and 2 represents step-1 and step-2), and the time-based data repeats the idle and data collection steps multiple times. **I would like to loop the csv file by checking the value of "Marker" column and separate the useful data steps and save each set of the data into separate excel sheet.

I have the following code in mind:

```
n=len(df)
i=0
newdf=[]

for i in range(0,n):
   if df.MARKER[i]==1:
       newdf.append(df.iloc[:,i])
   if df.MARKER[i]==0:
       end

return newdf
```

I have no thought about the remaining part of the codes yet since this is not able to proceed.

Comment: Why not just read in the csv file with pandas.read_csv and modify/filter the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to filter to elements where `MARKER == 1`. If that's the case, you could just do `newdf = df[df['MARKER'] == 1]`